# float imprecision in printf / appendFormat

Tags: objective-c, c

I have a float value, that I would like to show it in format string and if it corresponds to an int, showing the integer, if not, showing it with one decimal.

Like this :

```
3.1
3
2.9
2.8
```

For now I'm stuck, in the concept, I'd do something like that :

```
float myFloat = 3.1
float mySecondFloat = 3
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g %g", myFloat, mySecondFloat];
```

My question is:

1/ the type format "%g" works in most cases but sometimes i have result shown like "0.600001" while in reality there should be 0.6 because all I do is 0.7 - 0.1.

Is there a kind of type cast for float at 1 decimal or maybe a bitwise operation to get rid of the final imprecision, or other way to make it works in 100% of cases ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Your "reality" unfortunately does not coincide with the reality of the rest of the world, and in particular with the reality of your computer hardware :-(

Comment: Is your required precision always one decimal place?  If so, you might be better off storing things as ints (10 times bigger than the value you want them to be) and having a print function that puts a decimal point in the right place.  Otherwise, you will have problems with numbers that can't be exactly represented as floats (i.e. `0.6` in your example).

Comment: @KerrekSB can you redirect me to an article explaining the "reality of my computer hardware" which brings to this result. I'm just curious of how it works behind the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your need absolute precision when working with decimal numbers, you may consider using the `NSDecimalNumber` class.

[Number and Value Programming Topics: Using Decimal Numbers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/DecimalNumbers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000176-CJBCAGDI)

Otherwise, the `%.1g` format specifier will be OK.

Comment: Yes, I've read somewhere that NSDecimalNumber class was there to cover the imprecision of floats. I'll give it a try. the "%.1g" format specifier simply don't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this code:

```
float myFloat = 3.1
float mySecondFloat = 3
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f %.1f", myFloat, mySecondFloat];
```

EDIT:

If I really want to print the integer value of a float, i would do it this way (ugly code)

```
int intValue = myFloatNumber/1;
NSString *string;
if(myFloatNumber == intValue)
{
     string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", myFloatValue];
}
else
{
    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", myFloatValue];
}
```

Doing an integer division by 1, you automatically cast your float to an int.
Once you have the NSString *string you can concat it to your string.

Comment: That's what I'll do if I don't have any other option but this code will print out "3.1 3.0" and I would have prefered to show "3.1 3".

Comment: A float divided by an int yields a float; the divide by 1 is not what causes the implicit cast, its the fact that you're assigning it to an int.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing others answers, it seems that there is no standard C formatter to achieve this.

I went following Nicolas answer (NSDecimalNumber), hence the solve flag. It worked fine indeed, but, in my (very simple) case it might be overkill. Giving it a second thought, if I had to do it again, I think that I would go using only NSNumberFormatter on a NSNumber (using numberWithFloat: method)

If it can help someone..

Comment: I would use:  `[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:myFloat] stringValue];` as it automatically takes care of the +/- .00000001's.